# How to define and pass implicit encoder of a particular subtype to AvroSchema

Tags: scala, implicit, scalapb, avro4s

Is it possible to define and pass `Encoder[E]` for any subtype `E` (e.g. any `E` that extends `GeneratedEnum` class, in the code instance of `E` is `Color`) to `AvroSchema[C]` where `C` is some case class that contains `E` as field.

```scala
case class Color(value: Int) extends scalapb.GeneratedEnum // ... it has .name field
case class MyCaseClassWithEnum(color: Color) // ...

implicit def enumEncoder[E <: scalapb.GeneratedEnum]: Encoder[E] = new Encoder[E] {
  override def encode(e: E, schema: Schema, fieldMapper: FieldMapper): AnyRef = e.name
}

val actualSchema = AvroSchema[MyCaseClassWithEnum]
```

The full source code is [here](https://github.com/fpopic/proto-scalapb-to-avro4s/pull/1/files#diff-6e570058a227ad4a72cc7c36715f074965aad3d30bb77739dd4e361868467b97R12-R16)

Basically would like that any subtype instance of `GeneratedEnum` like `Color` encodes as `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define

```
implicit val schemaForColor: SchemaFor[Color] = new SchemaFor[Color]() {
  override def schema(fieldMapper: FieldMapper): Schema = 
    SchemaHelper.matchPrimitiveName("java.lang.String").get
}
```

or

```
implicit def schemaForColor[E <: GeneratedEnum]: SchemaFor[E] = new SchemaFor[E]() {
  override def schema(fieldMapper: FieldMapper): Schema =
    SchemaHelper.matchPrimitiveName("java.lang.String").get
}
```

Then the test `MyCaseClassWithEnumTest` passes.